# getting dataframe based on condition in dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a enigmatic task in Python. From API I receive a dictionary as shown below. From this response (dictionary) I have to make df which two columns. First is the SapId and the second is OOSOperation but only with rows where OOSOperation = 'OutOfStock'. Could anyone please help me with this task? I include picture.

[image: Dictionary case]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but maybe this is close to what you want:

```
products = data['Products'][:]

out_of_stock_products =[]

for product_dict in products:
  if product_dict['OOSOperation'] == 'OutOfStock':
    out_of_stock_products.append(product_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(out_of_stock_products)
```

Alternatively, using list comprehension:

```
products = data['Products'][:]

out_of_stock_products = [d for d in products if d['OOSOperation'] =='OutOfStock']

df = pd.DataFrame(out_of_stock_products)
```

Comment: It's really something I wanted! Really thank you! ;)

Comment: No problem :) I added another alternative that is similar, but uses list comprehension instead (where `d` is equivalent to the `product_dict` in the first answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could either prefilter with

```py
list_of_elements.filter(lambda element: element["OOSOperation"] == 'OutOfStock')
```

or just filter the DF afterwards with

```py
df[df["OOSOperation"] == 'OutOfStock']
```

Comment: The question is rather about how to create df, not how to filter df :) with method dict.to_df I get list with product in firts row.